# Remove tags on bulk from mantis BT

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

I have attached the tags Sprint1, Sprint2 .... Sprint8 on issues on mantis BT. After Sprint8 we want to start from Sprint1 again. So i need to delete all Sprint1 tags from those previous issues.

But there is only option for attaching new tags, not removing the existing tags. It can be done one by one but since there are more than 300 issues, i need a way to do so on bulk.

Anyone have any idea on this?
By the way, i am using mantisBT version 2.5.1 if it helps.
Or Is there any plugins for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have a similar need. I want to add tags in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

MantisBT currently does not offer any standard method to detach a tag from multiple issues in one single operation.

As a workaround, since you mentioned wanting to remove the tag from *all* issues it is attached to, what you can do is:

1. Go to *Manage Tags* page
2. Click on the `Sprint1` tag from the list (this will take you to the *Tag Details* page)
3. Delete the tag
4. Re-create the tag

Hope this helps.